# How to use the find/replace function with a variable number

Tags: notepad++

Seems simple enough but I cannot find this. I need to find all entries with _setvar_5

Then number 5 being a variable number. how do I find all of those entries and have it find the number but ignore what number it is?

TIA

Comment: okay got me there. I need to find all entries like that but the number changes on every entry.

Comment: please forgive my inability to properly ask the question. seriously.

Comment: I need to replace it the number portion as well.

Comment: there are one, two and three digit numbers but always a space after the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd> for (`Regular expressions` radio button selected <kbd>Alt+x</kbd>):

```
_setvar_([\d]+)
```

you can use `\1` = `([\d]+)` to extract this number later (in replace).